# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android how fix it?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

iam trying build cordova app, and return this menssage:

No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android.

(I am using Windows 10 SO)

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 40):

There's a workaround for this in [this Github issue comment](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15#issuecomment-426259512) as well as more detail surrounding the error in the issue itself, but in essence do this:

**Linux**

```
mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
```

**MacOS**

```
mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
```

**Windows**

```
mkdir %ANDROID_HOME%\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android\prebuilt\windows-x86_64
```

The ANDROID_HOME environment variable points to the root of the Android SDK installation.

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked for my Ionic 4 project on Linux.

Comment: sir i tried ur solution but in my ndk  path mips64el-linux-android file is not there instead of mips64el-linux-android is available?

Comment: `mips64el-linux-android ===  mips64el-linux-android` ???

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is rename `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle` to `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle-back` and reverse to use in Android Studio.